# Could not locate the function dllexport

Tags: windows, visual-studio, dll, dllexport

I have my dll project

```
// .h
#pragma once

#include <stdio.h>

extern "C"
{
void __declspec(dllexport) __stdcall sort(int* vect, int size);
}

//.cpp
#include "stdafx.h"

void __declspec(dllexport) __stdcall sort(int* vect, int size)
{

}
```

And I have my console project:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


/* Pointer to the sort function defined in the dll. */
typedef void (__stdcall *p_sort)(int*, int);


int _tmain(int argc, LPTSTR argv[])
{
    p_sort sort;

    HINSTANCE hGetProcIDDLL = LoadLibrary("dllproj.dll");

    if (!hGetProcIDDLL) 
    {
        printf("Could not load the dynamic library\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    sort = (p_sort)GetProcAddress(hGetProcIDDLL, "sort");

    if (!sort)
    {
        FreeLibrary(hGetProcIDDLL);
        printf("Could not locate the function %d\n", GetLastError());
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    sort(NULL, 0);

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that my function sort colud not be located, that is the function `GetProcAddress` always returns `NULL`.

Why? How can i fix it?

EDIT: using `__cdecl` (in the dll project instead of `__stdcall`) and `Dependency Walker` as suggested:

[image]

I also changed the following (in my main), but it still doesn't work.

```
typedef void (__cdecl *p_sort)(int*, int);
```

Comment: If you are going to use GetProcAddress, then you need to use a DEF file to remove the decorations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is exported with a decorated name. For debugging purposes, when faced with such a situation, use `dumpbin` or Dependency Walker to find out what that name is. I predict it will be: `_sort@8`. The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zxk0tw93.aspx) for the `__stdcall` calling convention gives decoration rules as follows:

> **Name-decoration convention**: An underscore (_) is prefixed to the name. The name is followed by the at sign (@) followed by the number of bytes (in decimal) in the argument list. Therefore, the function declared as `int func( int a, double b )` is decorated as follows: `_func@12`

You'll have to do one of the following:

1. Use the decorated name when importing.
2. Use `__cdecl` to avoid the decoration.
3. Export with a .def file to avoid the decoration.

Comment: I tried replacing __stdcall with __cdecl, anyway I got the same error.

Comment: And let me guess, you only changed the exe but not the dll.

Comment: And when you looked at the DLL using dumpbin or Dependency Walker?

Comment: If I use Dependency Walker I can see the function name is _sort@8 (when I use stdcall), so I changed the string "sort" to "_sort@8" as GetProcAddress function argument, and I still get the same error: the function can't be located...

Comment: If the function is exported as `_sort@8` then it is `__stdcall`. If the function is exported as `_sort@8` then passing `"_sort@8"` to `GetProcAddress` will succeed. Most likely you are getting confused with rebuilding, copying files around, using out of date files etc. The information in my answer is accurate.

Comment: Well, if I use stdcall and "_sort@8" it doesn't work, if I use cdecl and "sort" it doesn't work, even if Dependency Walker shows me these names...

Comment: If the DLL really exports a function named `sort`, then passing `"sort"` to `GetProcAddress` will succeed. Ergo, the DLL that you loaded does not export a function with that name.

Comment: If you load that DLL then passing `"sort"` to `GetProcAddress` will succeed. Again, you clearly are not using that DLL. You must have multiple copies of the DLL and are loading the wrong one. Do make sure that you load the right one. How is your program finding the DLL? It will look first in the same directory as the executable. Is that how it is located?

Comment: I had only one copy of this dll. I deleted it and rebuild (again) my solution. Now it works, thanks.